# Confused about C++ inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

Code snippet:

```
class A
{
    protected:
    int b;
};

class B : public A
{

};

struct C : B
{
    int call (const C&);
};

class D : B
{
    int call (const C&);
};

int C::call (const C& c)
{
    return c.b;
}

int D::call (const C& c)
{
    return c.b;
}

int main (void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Why `c.b` can be accessed in `C::call()` but not in `D::call()`?

Don't they the same? Both of them are referenced from the outside!

Here is the error message GCC compiler gives:

```
main.cpp: In member function 'int D::call(const C&)':
main.cpp:4:9: error: 'int A::b' is protected
     int b;
         ^
main.cpp:29:14: error: within this context
     return c.b;
              ^
```

Comment: Because C is not a superclass of D and protected modifier allows to access to the protected field/methods only to the class and subclasses of a class.

Comment: I didnt try to compile, but I am just wondering: What makes you think that one works and the other not? Arent they exactly the same?

Comment: @tobi303 Compiler gives different results!

Comment: ...well now I got it ;)

Comment: what does the compiler say?

Comment: @tobi303 I edited, and the error message is given above. :-)

Comment: Actually in a first case you aren't reference it from outside - it is from inside the C class implementation. In other words the assumption "Don't they the same? Both of them are referenced from the outside!" isn't true

Comment: Why? They are referenced from the outside! Aren't they?

Comment: No. Implementation of the `int C::call (const C& c)` method is a subset of the implementation of the C class and as such you can access in it all, even private, members of the C class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inheritance tree is the following:
[image]

So C is a B which is itself an A.   As b is protected, C and B can access the b they've inherited from A.

Similarly, D is a B which is itself an A. So D and B can access the b they've inherited from A.

However C and D are not directly related.  They are like strangers for another.  So C cannot see the b from a D, nor can a D see the b from a C.

### Looking at your code:

First, in the following code, you don't return the b member of the object. You return the b of another C object that you pass as parameter:

```
int C::call (const C& c)
{
    return c.b;
}
```

Regardles of this detail, any member functions of C has access to all the members of any C object. So this function is valid C++ code.

The next function does not work as well:

```
int D::call (const C& c)
{
    return c.b;
}
```

THe parameter passed to this member function of D is of class C.  As we have seen above, C and D are not directly related. So C objects are like a black box for member functions of D.  Hence the function can only access the public members of C.

THis is why you get this error message:  a D object doesn't have access to protected or private members of a C object.